# Использование прокси в Python

Tags: python

При попытке использовать любое прокси выдает ошибку:

```
NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x03BA44C0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] Попытка установить соединение была безуспешной, т.к. от другого компьютера
за требуемое время не получен нужный отклик, или было разорвано уже установленное соединение из-за неверного отклика уже подключенного компьютера')))
```

Это ошибка возникла недавно. Прокси беру с этого сайта https://www.us-proxy.org/

Comment: А где же сам код этой попытки??

Comment: `proxy = {"http": "http://193.8.46.22:8080"}
                
r = requests.get(i, headers = headers, proxies = proxy)`

Comment: вместо i ссылка

Comment: добавьте свой код в вопрос, а не в комментарий.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Таймаут же, прокся скорее всего не работает. Публичные прокси нужно брать пачками и проверять на валидность:

```
file = open('proxies.txt', 'r')
proxies = file.read().splitlines()

for i in proxies:
    try:
        proxy = {
            'https': i
        }

        r = requests.get(i, headers = headers, proxies = proxy)


    except:
        continue
```

Comment: У меня есть проверка, но все равно это ошибка иногда возникает

Comment: Это же публичные прокси, они через раз работают все. Если нужна стабильность - только приватные